# how to draw multi lines in a line chart using JFreeChart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am working with java, I want to draw a line chart which includes at least two lines at the same time. I can only pass one DefaultCategoryDataset each time as a parameter, and this DefaultCategoryDataset represent one line. so how can I do that?

```
ChartFactory.createLineChart("String", "String", "String", "DefaultCategoryDataset", "PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL", "boolean", "boolean", "boolean");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to "feed" data with more than one series.

Here it is how i handle this with XYLineChart:

1) I have a private object

```
    private XYSeriesCollection data =null;
```

2) It is initialised into a method and then another method that "feeds" data is called.

```
    data = new XYSeriesCollection();

    fillXYSeries();
```

3) Here is this method:

```
private void fillXYSeries(){

    data.removeAllSeries();

    for(int i=0;i<tables.size();i++){

        final XYSeries series = new XYSeries(tables.get(i).getName());

        for(int j=0;j<mostIntensiveTables.get(i).getChangesForChart().size();j++){
            series.add(j,mostIntensiveTables.get(i).getChangesForChart().get(j));
        }

        int found=0;
        for(int k=0;k<data.getSeriesCount();k++){
            if(data.getSeries(k)==series){
                found=1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(found==0){
            data.addSeries(series);
        }
    }

}
```

and finally i construct my chart with data object as parameter:

```
final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
            "Most Updated Tables",
            "Version ID", 
            "Number of Changes", 
            data,
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
            true,
            true,
            false
    );
```